# How to replicate same array variable multiple times in PHP?

Tags: php, arrays, variables

Alright, i have setup this code and it works,

Original format

```
array(196)
```

That i used the following command to replicate twice (to be used as variable in curlopt_postfields).

```
$pid=196;
$qty=2;
$quantity = trim(str_repeat("{$pid},", $_POST['qty']), ',');
$postfields["pid"] = $quantity;
$quantity = array_fill(0, $_POST['qty'], $pid);
```

And the output is

```
196
196
```

Now i want to encode this in the same format

```
array(base64_encode(serialize(array("486" => "windows|Windows"))))
```

Can anyone help me?

Answer (score 0):

Never mind, found the solution..

```
$window = base64_encode(serialize(array("486" => "windows|Windows")));
$windows = trim(str_repeat("{$window},", $_POST['qty']), ',');
$postfields["window"] = $windows;
$windows = array_fill(0, $_POST['qty'], $window);
```